# How do I do Euler 5 without bruteforcing?

Tags: java, algorithm, brute-force

In my current [Project Euler problem 5](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5), I have a "working" solution.  It works on smaller numbers (the example one in the question), but not on the actual problem, because I'm brute forcing it, and the program doesn't finish.

Here's the explanation of the problem:

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is **evenly divisible<sup>1</sup>** by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?
>
> <sup>1</sup>: Divisible with no remainder

Here is my current code:

```
package Euler;

public class Euler5 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int desiredNumber = 20;
    boolean exitLoop = false;
    long counter = 1;

    while(exitLoop == false) {
        long loopCounter = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<=desiredNumber; i++) {
            if(counter % i == 0) {
                loopCounter++;
            }
        }
        if(loopCounter == desiredNumber) {
            exitLoop = true;
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
        counter++;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Euler 5 is a problem on projecteuler.net

Comment: You should use [LCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) for an efficient solution

Comment: @Cflo Please include the problem statement for Euler 5 here, so that people potentially answering need not go off-site.

Comment: You can solve that problem using a piece of paper, a pen (or a pencil) and a calculator.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a computer to answer this question. Look: if a number can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 20 it means that it should be a multiplication of primes in corresponding powers:

```
   2**4 (from 16) 
   3**2 (from 9)
   5
   7
  11 
  13
  17
  19
```

so the solution is

```
  16 * 9 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19 == 232792560
```

since the answer is *quite large* I doubt if brute force is a *reasonable method* here.

In ***general case*** (for some `n >= 2`) find out all the *prime numbers* that are not exeeding the n:

```
  2, 3, ..., m (m <= n)
```

then, for each prime number `a` find out the power `pa` such that

`a**pa <= n`

but

`a**(pa + 1) > n`

the answer will be

`2**p2 * 3**p3 * ... * m**pm`

Possible Java implementation:

```
  public static BigInteger evenlyDivisible(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");
    else if (n <= 2)
      return BigInteger.valueOf(n);

    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    primes.add(2);

    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2) {
      boolean isPrime = true;

      for (int p : primes) {
        if (i % p == 0) {
          isPrime = false;

          break;
        }
        else if (p * p > i)
          break;
      }

      if (isPrime)
        primes.add(i);
    }

    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;

    for(int p : primes) {
      // Simplest implemenation, check for round up errors however
      int power = (int)(Math.log(n) / Math.log(p));

      result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(p).pow(power));
    }

    return result;
  }
```

...

```
  System.out.println(evenlyDivisible(20)); // 232792560
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this, however the point of the Euler problems (at least for me) is to gain coding skills:p

Comment: @Cflo: For coding skills try implement my algorithm (see my edit as a possible solution). Euler project problems are teasing ones: samples are easy to verify (including brute force) but the main questions deserve elaborated implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The number you are seeking is the **[Least common multiple (LCM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)** of the numbers 1,2,3,...,20.

By splitting each numbers to the multiplication of its prime factors (easy for small numbers), finding LCM is fairly easy.